# adding extra dimensions in a numpy array or a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, python-xarray

I have a pandas series named obs(62824,) that has values of temperatures as follows

```
0        16.9
1        11.0
2         5.9
3         9.4
4        15.4
        ...
```

I want to use the following code to basically transform my numpy array to a xr.DataArray

```
lat = 35.93679
lon = 14.45663
obs_data = xr.DataArray(obs_tas, dims=['time','lat','lon'], \
                       coords=[pd.date_range('1979-01-01', '2021-12-31', freq='D'), lat, lon])
```

My issue is that I get the following error

```
ValueError: dimensions ('lat',) must have the same length as the number of data dimensions, ndim=0
```

from my understanding is because the numpy array has only 1 dimension. I tried the following

```
obs = obs[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
```

However that did not work as well and I still get the same error.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct about adding dimensions to `obs`.

In [Creating a DataArray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#creating-a-dataarray) and [API reference](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.html#xarray.DataArray) it is mentioned that the coordinates themselves should be array-like.

Your `lat` and `lon` are floats. I believe all you have to do is wrap them in a list, like so:

```py
lat = [35.93679]  # <- list
lon = [14.45663]  # <- list
obs_data = xr.DataArray(
    obs[:, None, None], 
    dims=['time', 'lat', 'lon'], 
    coords=[
        pd.date_range('1979-01-01', '2021-12-31', freq='D'), lat, lon
    ]
)
```